# How to disconnect cleanly from MySQL in R?

Tags: mysql, r

This function does not close connections properly (so I reach a max limit of 16, which is not good obviously):

```
query.test = function(query) {
  con = dbConnect(MySQL(), groups = 'test')
  output = tryCatch({
    dbGetQuery(con, query)
    }, warning = function(w) {
      print(w)
    }, error = function(e) {
      print(e)
    }, finally  = function() {
      dbDisconnect(con)
    })
  return(output)
}
```

I thought that statements in the `finally` clause always get executed, so it's not clear to me why this code does not work.

Comment: why don't you connect once at the top of the page? run all your queries on the page without having to connect, and then just close it once at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @nathanhayfield There are a lot of ways to accomplish the same thing, but I am specifically asking why this way doesn't work. I'm trying to learn something new here.

Comment: @EvanZamir So is your interest more in why the finally doesn't run or how to make it so the function disconnects from the database?

Comment: @Dason I can get it to disconnect by initiating the connection outside of the tryCatch. What I'd really like to know is why it doesn't work the way I've written it inside the tryCatch.

Answer (score 3):

The answer turns out to be a bit of strange (to me) R syntax:

```
query.test = function(query) {
  output = tryCatch({
    con = dbConnect(MySQL(), groups = 'test')
    dbGetQuery(con, query)
    }, warning = function(w) {
      print("warning!")
    }, error = function(e) {
      print("error encountered!")
      print(e)
    }, finally = {
      dbDisconnect(con)
      print("goodbye")
    })  
  return(output)
}
```

The difference here is:

```
}, finally  = function() {
      dbDisconnect(con)
    })
```

should be

```
}, finally  = {
      dbDisconnect(con)
    })
```

If anyone has insight into why the `finally` doesn't work the first way, I'd appreciate hearing it.

Comment: I believe the distinction is that `warning` and `error` expect "handlers", i.e. functions, whereas `finally` is expecting only an expression. Scanning the documentation, it seems reasonable to me that it could be somewhat clearer on this point, I suppose.

Comment: @joran Yeah, that seems to be the case. There must be some technical reason why finally is handled differently.